# error in parallel processing in python using dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe *HH* that looks like this:

```
     end_Date  latitude  longitude start_Date
0    9/5/2014   41.8927   -90.4031   4/1/2014
1    9/5/2014   41.8928   -90.4031   4/1/2014
2    9/5/2014   41.8927   -90.4030   4/1/2014
3    9/5/2014   41.8928   -90.4030   4/1/2014
4    9/5/2014   41.8928   -90.4029   4/1/2014
5    9/5/2014   41.8923   -90.4028   4/1/2014
```

I am trying to parallelize my function using multiprocessing package in python:
here's what i wrote:

```
if __name__ =='__main__':    
    pool = Pool(200)
    start = time.time()
    print "Hello"
    H = pool.map(funct_parallel, HH)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/testparallel.py", line 198, in <module>
    H = pool.map(funct_parallel, HH)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

not sure where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pool.map` requires an `iterable` as second argument that it feeds to the `function` [see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map).

If you iterate over the `DataFrame`, you get the `column` names - hence the complaint about the `string indices`.

```
for i in df:
    print(i)

end_Date
latitude
longitude
start_Date
```

You need instead to break the `DataFrame` into pieces that can be processed in parallel by the `pool`, for instance by reading the file in `chunks` as explained in the [I/O docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).